# how do I get this function to run

Tags: c++

Im having trouble with calculating correct answers and determining weather a function returns true or false

```
char correctAnswers[] = {'B','D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'};
char studentAnswers[10] = {};
```

I have my student answers and the correct answers stored like this ^^^

```
bool grade(char correctAnswers[], char studentAnswers[]){
    int j = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
                if(correctAnswers[b]==studentAnswers[j]){
                    b++;
                    j++;
                    ++ansCorrect;
                    
                }
    }
                

    
    if(ansCorrect >= 8){//8 out of 10 correct
        return true;}
    else;
        return false;
}
```

then with this piece of code I am trying to check each answer the user inputs to see if it matches the given answer on the corresponding index (1,1)(2,2)(3,3) etc.

```
if (grade()==true){
    cout << "Congratulations!\nYou have passed exam.\n";
}
    if (grade()==false){
    cout << "Sorry, you have not passed the exam!\n";}
```

This piece of code is 100 % wrong, but I am trying to use it as a reference as to what I need, I need to take the grade function and check if it returned true or false

Comment: Why do you think the code is 100% wrong? You have a misplaced `;` here: `else;`  and its unclear where and how `ansCorrect` is initialized

Answer (score 1):

Your loop logic is pretty wild.  I remember seeing your question yesterday, and had pointed out many issues with it.  Looks like you tried to take some of that on board and fix your loop but it's still really broken.

The issue is you only ever increment `b` and `j` if you get a correct answer.  So, ask yourself: what if the values don't match?  Well, you never increment your indices and so every subsequent iteration of the loop is testing the same values.

The way to test each element against the corresponding one is to use the loop variable `x` as an index.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    if (correctAnswers[x] == studentAnswers[x]) {
        ++ansCorrect;
    }
}
```

With a few extra tidy-ups, your function can become:

```
bool grade(char correctAnswers[], char studentAnswers[])
{
    int ansCorrect = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        ansCorrect += (correctAnswers[x] == studentAnswers[x]);
    }
    return ansCorrect >= 8;
}
```

And you should change how you call it.  Right now, you're calling it twice.  Just use `else`.  And try to avoid comparing boolean values to `true`.  Either omit the comparison completely, or test that it's not `false`.  The reason is that not all "true-like" values are equal to `true`.  In C++, *any* non-zero value can be a logical truth, whereas zero is *always* false.

So, while this may seem to be splitting hairs for a type like `bool` which does have guarantees, getting in the habit of avoiding "equals true" tests will help you not create bugs in future when you are working on more complex programs.

```
if (grade(correctAnswers, studentAnswers)) {
    cout << "Congratulations!\nYou have passed exam.\n";
} else {
    cout << "Sorry, you have not passed the exam!\n";
}
```

Note that the error you mention in the comments suggests that wherever you are calling `grade` from (probably in `main` function?) might not have seen a definition of that function (code is compiled from the top down).

In that case, you can either move the entire function above `main` or you can pre-declare the function (otherwise known as a "function prototype") by adding this line somewhere above your `main`.  Then when the compiler sees you try to call `grade` it will know what that function looks like, even though it's not yet defined:

```
bool grade(char correctAnswers[], char studentAnswers[]);
```

Comment: I see what your saying, but I can't get rid of this error -- undefined symbol: grade(char const*, char*) -- it doesn't show up on a specific line rather it just announces itself when I run the program I can't see to get ri oof it so I can run my program.

Comment: I have edited the answer.  Note that I fixed the `grade` call (which was just copied from your original question and did not include its arguments).  I also added a comment about the error you're seeing, its probable cause, and two ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the ";"after "else" is a bug.
and you can try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool grade(char correctAnswers[], char studentAnswers[])
{
    int ansCorrect = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (correctAnswers[i] == studentAnswers[i])
        {
            ansCorrect++;
        }
    }
    if (ansCorrect >= 8)
    { // 8 out of 10 correct
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

int main()
{
    char correctAnswers[] = {'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'};
    char studentAnswers[10] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> studentAnswers[i];
        cin.ignore();
    }
    if (grade(correctAnswers, studentAnswers) == true)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations!\nYou have passed exam.\n";
    }
    else if (grade(correctAnswers, studentAnswers) == false)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, you have not passed the exam!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: No, while that rogue semi-colon is potentially a dormant bug and definitely a mistake, it makes no logical difference in the function's behavior in this case.  If the semi-colon is there, the `else` will do nothing and then the function will return false.  If the semi-colon is not there, the `else` will cause the function to return false.